# why is string s = (char*)tag.c_str(); is wrong when tag is a string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

why is the following code is wrong ?

`string tag = "hello"; string s = (char*)tag.c_str();`

what does this mean: `storing addresses to internal storage of temporary string objects is wrong.`
can someone please help? What exactly happens during above conversion?

Comment: I don't think that error message is correct. What is producing it? Of course you don't need the `(char*)` cast. In both cases all that is happening is fresh storage is being allocated and the characters are copied to the new storage, so there is no storing of addresses.

Comment: What is `(char*)tag.c_str()` meant to do? `c_str()` already returns a `const char*` and `std::string` has a constructor which takes `const char*`. But otherwise your code is fine, there must be a different error in a code you haven't posted.

Comment: Why are you casting the `c_str()` pointer to a non-const `char*`? `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, and `std::string` has a constructor and assignment operator that accept `const char*` as input.  `string s = tag.c_str();` will work fine (but you should use `string s = tag;` instead).

Comment: Does the message refers to *exactly* that code? To me, it looks like you have an over-sensitive static analysis tool.

Comment: It compiles https://godbolt.org/z/vbGPM3

Comment: @Zhang a code that compiles and shows the expected result only means that it is free from syntax errors. It does not guarantee that it is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The quoted message is wrong for the shown example because `tag` is not a "temporary string object", but rather a variable with longer lifetime than the pointer. It is also wrong because the pointer is only used within the full-expression where `c_str` was called, so the pointer is not being "stored" for later.

The cast to `char*` is unnecessary and should be removed. Also, the call to  `c_str` is unnecessary. A simpler way to copy the string is this:

```
std::string s = tag;
```

---

Here is a *wrong* program for which the message would be correct:

```
const char* wrong = "wrong"s.c_str(); // don't do this
std::cout << wrong; // kaboom; behaviour of program is undefined
```

Here, addresses to internal storage of temporary string object is being stored, and it is wrong because the temporary string object is immediately destroyed and therefore the pointer is invalid and therefore useless.

Answer (score -2):

`string tag = "hello";`

Initializes `tag` object with value of `"hello"`. Exactly hos `tag` does that is not your concern. It does it and that is all you need to know (for now).

`string s = (char*)tag.c_str();`

First you ask `tag` object to give you access to its internal buffer where it is storing string data (see [c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) description). You then change original return type (`const char*`), then use that to initialize new `std::string` object.

I don't know what intentions you have with `s`, but one of the following would be a better choice:

```c
std::string s = tag; // s is now a copy of tag.
std::string &s = tag; // s is now a reference to tag (what you do t s will be reflected on tag).
std::string s(std::move(tag)); // contents of tag moved to s
```

If for some reason you need to access the memory hidden inside `std::string` (that is what `c_str()` method does), you definitely shouldn't throw away `const`. You may think it works, but it would be better to say that *it works now*.

Not only is storing addresses to internal storage of temporary string objects wrong, mostly storing address to internal storage of string is wrong -- the fact that it is a temporary object only makes it worse. Here are two reasons:

1. Since the object is temporary it means that that address will definitely be invalid the moment the object is destroyed. By *invalid* I mean that it will no longer point to start of string. It will still point somewhere, but who knows that that will be.
2. Even if object wasn't temporary, storing that address is dangerous. Say someone assigned a new value to that string, something long. The way `std::string` is implemented may either lead to allocation or reallocation. That means that object now uses different place to store its data. The old place gets released and thus becomes available for reuse by others. You are still holding old pointer which now points to what? Who knows!

Comment: `string s = (char*)tag.c_str();` does not store the address of the contents of `tag` in `s`. It copies the contents of the null-terminated character string given by `c_str()`. So `string s = tag.c_str();`  is (if `tag` does not contain `\0` in the middle of the string)  will have the same result as doing `std::string s = tag;`